# how to include (i.e. execute) a file in psql but only if it exists?

Tags: psql

Sometimes for automated scripts/systems you need to be able to check if a file exists before attempting to execute it. psql doesn't have a native means for this, so I need a way to accomplish the same using native code.

I looked around for a solution to this and was surprised that I didn't find anything. Posting my solution here for anyone who might be able to use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As a general template, this is a pretty compact way of doing it:

```
\if `[ -f "<file_path>" ] && echo 1 || echo 0`
    -- file exists
    \i <file_path>
\else
    -- file doesn't exist
\endif
```

The "else" part is obviously optional.